# Match same pattern multiple times

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which has the following structure :

```
~ foo;
text 1
~ foo;
text 2
~ foo;
...
~ foo;
text n
~ foo;
```

I am trying to get `text 1, text 2 .. text n` into an array, but I can't figure it out how to do this, so my question is : **How to get this information into an array?**

I tried the following regex : `!~\s*([a-z0-9 ]+)\s*(;|\r|\r\n)([^~]*)~\s*\\1!i`, but it seems that it matches only first occurrence. ( I tried [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) )

** UPDATE : Example :**

**My String :**

```
// .. text before... //
~ Key; 
  some random text
~ Key;
  another random text
~ Key;

// .. some random text .. //

~ Key2; some random text again
~ Key2; 
another some random text again
~ Key2;
```

**And the output should be :**

```
Array
(
    [Key] => Array
        (
            [0] => some random text
            [1] => another some random text
        )

    [Key2] => Array
        (
            [0] => some radom text again
            [1] => another some radom text again
        )

)
```

*It doesn't need to be fully done with regex*

Comment: does it always 1,2,3,4,5,6,..n after text?

Comment: http://regexr.com/38p97

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years no, it will be completely different text

Comment: @John is `foo` dynamic?

Comment: How about ~ foo;? Is it always before text

Comment: @Hamza, there is only one foo for one block of text, but there can be foo2 for the next text, so that have to be added also into an array

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years, yes, but foo have to be the KEY of the array

Comment: Why dont you process the text line-by-line, skip all those that start with `~`, and add all others to your collection?

Comment: @SebastianH text can be very large and it won't be always separated in multiple lines

Comment: @John I'm a bit too lazy/tired at the moment to post a full answer with explanation, so here you go with [*a solution*](https://eval.in/143801).

Comment: @HamZa awesome! It works as expected! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An original way to use preg_replace_callback to obtain the whished structure:

```
$pattern = '/^~ (\w+);\s*(.+?)\s*(?=\R~ \1;)/ms';
$res = array();

preg_replace_callback($pattern,
                      function ($m) use (&$res) { $res[$m[1]][] = $m[2]; },
                      $str);

print_r($res);
```

Note: I assumed that the "random text" can be multiline, if it is not the case you can change the pattern to `/^~ (\w+);\h*\R?\h*(\N+?)\h*(?=\R~ \1;)/m`

`\R` is a shortcut for an atomic group that contains any type of newlines.
`\N` matches all characters except newlines whatever the mode (singleline or not)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep trying with `preg_match_all`, because in all honesty that is the tool that you require.

The reason is because it performs a **global** search, which is exactly what you express as a requirement when you say this:

> "but it seems that it matches only first occurrence."

That's what `preg_match_all` is for.

---

Anyway, the problem with your regex is the backreference `\1`.

When you capture `text 1`, it keeps looking for `text 1` instead of `text \d` like you would like it to.

If you can give a more realistic sample of your data, I can create an expression for it.